# What happens if you put /dev/urandom into a shell script and run it?

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, random

I want to know what happens when you run the contents of /dev/urandom as a shell script. I know when you `cat` it into a terminal it will set off a bunch of random things in the terminal environment. Does this work for shell scripts as well?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I don't know about that; even if it doesn't mess up my macOS installation, it might delete my whole iCloud Drive or something.

Comment: An invaluable skill is to learn how to test things in a "sandbox" environment, where you have safeguards in place to limit the damage that an errant command might be able to do.

Comment: The chances of bricking the computer are far higher than having it output the Complete Works of Shakespeare. Unless it randomly generates `wget -r -l 9999 --quota=inf https://www.thecompleteworksofshakespeare.com`, of course. That is much more likely (and it actually exists)

Answer (score 1):

**Literally anything at all** can happen, so you probably shouldn't do it. However, you should probably expect mostly syntax errors though.

Pipe `/dev/urandom` to `sh` if you want to see this. You can try this with<sup>1</sup>

```bash
cat /dev/urandom | sh
```

The first time I ran it, it gave

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

A couple more tries and I got it to run 3 lines (unsuccessfully) before it tried doing stuff with randomly named files.

Eventually it started writing garbled text after what I assume is the [terminal switching modes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/unicode.html#term) or something.

[image: Image showing garbled text in a terminal]

And then a few attempts later it returned to the top of the screen. More fun stuff. Mostly errors though.

<sup>1: Yes, I know, UUOC, but it's easier for me to remember.</sup>

Comment: But if run billions of times, `/dev/urandom` will eventually come up with `systemd`.  Actually, it might do it faster than that.

Comment: Could someone calculate the probability of getting `rm -rf /*` ran as a result? It would be funny to know.

Comment: Ok so, if I understand properly, the value of a random byte from /dev/urandom can be any value from 0 to 255. `rm -rf /*` is 9 characters, plus the line return that you would need after to run the command, making it 10 characters long. 10 * 256 = 2560 so we have a 1/2560 probability to get the computer nuked by rm every time we run this command. :P

Comment: The number of possible combinations that doesn't nuke the computer (using `rm -rf /*`) is: `255^10 = 1.162523670191533 * 10^24` (9 chars + NULL terminator). So the chance of nuking your PC like that is practically zero.

Comment: @mutageneral with probabilities AND is a multiplication, so 1/256 for the first letter, AND 1/256 for the second etc to the 10th character is 1/256 * 1/256 * ... which can be written as (1/256)¹⁰

Comment: @mutageneral you also need that the start of a line, since `foorm ...` won't do. So 11 correct chars. Or it could be with eg. semicolons instead of newlines. And it can't be inside a quoted string. So not that easy to calculate.

Comment: No need for `/*` at the end of the command, either `/` or `*` does quite some damage. `-fr` is the same as `-rf`. Even without the `r` or `f` it's dangerous. Think of simply `rm *`. The trailing char can be a `\n` or `;` or `&` etc. Also, none of you have taken into account that it's not just the first command that's executed; pretty much anywhere after noise if this command arrives between two proper separator then it starts removing contents.

Comment: A string like `>x\n` already wipes out the contents of the file `x` if it existed. Repeat for about 62 reasonably named one-char filenames, for `;` or `&` token at the end... And again, it can appear anywhere later in the stream. The probablily of doing some damage to your system is much-much-much bigger than that 10^-24 -ish calculated earlier. It _is_ a significant risk.

Comment: I hardly ever downvote an answer, but this time I did, because it encourages OP to execute a command that could quite easily cause irreversible and unknown damage, and doesn't even give due warning about it.

Comment: Did you really try this as root? That's... a really, really bad, horrible, crazy idea. NEVER run random things as root! There is no need to do it as root and doing so creates a security risk out of thin air.

Comment: @egmont no, `rm -rf /` is perfectly safe and has been for several years. See [POSIX rm](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html): "*If [...] an operand resolves to the root directory, rm shall write a diagnostic message to standard error and do nothing more [...]."*.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the clarification! I didn't know this. But even if it's implemented on _every_ Unix system like this, it doesn't change the very point of my comments here :)

Comment: @terdon I did it in a VM. There was no risk. :) Note the `/home/user` and `root@debian`.

Comment: @terdon @egmont This is incredibly dangerously incorrect in the real world. By this definition, almost all `rm` implementations except for a rounding error (including the GNU one (since it's overridable)) fail to meet this standard. It's generally unlikely that you'll see something strictly conforming to this.

Comment: @JustineKrejcha the standard `rm` on Linux and all POSIX compliant systems (except some very, very old ones) renders `rm -rf /` harmless. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix)#Protection_of_the_filesystem_root. It's been more than 15 years since any commonly used system has shipped with an `rm` which would allow `rm -rf /`, as far as I know. GNU `rm` most certainly does not.

Comment: It does increase the rarity (of random chance, accidental stuff) quite significantly (in practice: wiping some directories makes the system pretty useless, good luck booting after you've wiped the kernel image from disk), but it shouldn't be ***assumed*** to be harmless.

Comment: I think @egmont's ultimate point was that the answer insufficiently warns against doing dangerous things, which I've gone ahead and corrected in the answer and I do agree.

Comment: Whether or not `rm -rf /` is protected, there are shorter commands out there like `rm -r ~`, `rm *`, `>x` etc. that can cause damage. `rm -rf /*` (if interrupted quickly) is typically way less harmful than e.g. `rm *`, a user's personal data (if not backed up properly) is way more precious and way harder to recover (if possible at all) than to reinstall a system.